# Trouble with hash lookup in bison

Tags: c++, bison, unordered-map

I'm working on a sort of the classic bison/flex calculator implementation problem.   The issue that I've run is with variable assignment.  It seems to work at first; only declared variables can be referenced, it remembers the value that I've assigned... except that all variables seem to share a single value, rather than each having its own.  So if I do "x=3; y=5;" then both x and y have the value of 5.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure if this is a failure in my understanding of bison, c++, or how the unordered_map data structure works.  (Or perhaps, all 3)

I believe I have included all the relevant parts of the code below, but if there is some missing, let me know.

```
%{

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <unordered_map>
    using namespace std;

    unordered_map<string, double> dict;
%}    

%union {
    double dval;
    char *sval;
}

%token <sval> VARIABLE
%token <dval> NUMBER
%type<dval> expr

%%

assign: 
     VARIABLE '=' expr {dict[$1] = $3; cout << $1<< "="<<dict[$1]<<endl; }
expr: VARIABLE {
    if(dict.find($1) == dict.end())
    {
        yyerror("Bad Var");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem turned out to be not in how I was storing the data, but just in retrieving it.  I needed to add the else statement below to actually set the value of expr.

```
expr: VARIABLE {
    if(dict.find($1) == dict.end())
    {
        yyerror("Bad Var");
    }
    else { //Needed this section
        $$ = dict[$1]
    }
}
```

I think I knew I needed to do that and just forgot, but the behavior of expr taking the value of whatever the most recently assigned variable is threw me off.

Answer (score 2):

You should really show your flex code as well, but I'm guessing that the relevant bit looks something like this:

```
{id}     { yylval.sval = yytext; return VARIABLE; }
```

What you need to do is:

```
{id}     { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return VARIABLE; }
```

And then you need to make sure that you don't leak memory, by freeing the allocated string after you use it in your bison action.

See [the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/A-Note-About-yytext-And-Memory.html) and [the bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Strings-are-Destroyed.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, `std::string` is not a POD-type, so you can't put it in a union prior to C++11, and even then, it wouldn't work as bison does not create the necessary copy ctor and assignment operator for the union.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, good points. Rather than trying to write all the warnings, I'll just delete the suggestion.